# Java read student records and calculate high low and average for each quiz

Tags: java, arrays, class, io, readfile

**Update:** Thank you so much for all your input! I figured out that my low returns all 0s because java initializes all integers 0 so I changed it to int lowScore [] = new int [] {100, 100, 100, 100, 100}. The problem with findAvg is that in main i created an array of student [40] but the file only contains 15 students, which is why I cannot use a.length to find average. I've added codes to count the number of lines.

I am working on an assignment about reading a txt file of student ID along with their 5 quiz scores. The assignment is asking to read those scores up to 40 students and calculate the high, low and average for each quiz.

Sample output:

Stud   Quiz1  Quiz2  Quiz3  Quiz4  Quiz5

1234    90     100    90     98     80

1243    92     92     90     98     70

High Score:    92  100 90  98  80

Low Score:     90  92  90  98  70

Average Score: 91  96 90 98  75

I've created 4 classes: student class for ID and scores, statistics class to calculate high, low and average, util class for read file function, and driver class for the main.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class Student {
    private int SID;
    private int scores[] = new int[5];

    public int getSID() {
        return SID;
    }

    public void setSID(int sID) {
        SID = sID;
    }

    public int getScores(int index) {
        return scores[index];
    }

    public void setScores(int[] scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }

    public void printSID() {
        System.out.println(SID);
    }

    public void printScores() {
        for (int x : scores) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}

class Statistics {

    private final int[] lowscores = new int[5];
    private final int[] highscores = new int[5];
    private final float[] avgscores = new float[5];

    public void findlow(Student[] a) {
        for (Student stu : a) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                lowscores[i] = Math.min(lowscores[i], stu.getScores(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public void findhigh(Student[] a) {
        for (Student stu : a) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                highscores[i] = Math.max(highscores[i], stu.getScores(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public void findavg(Student[] a) {
        int[] sum = new int[5];
        for (Student stu : a) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                sum[i] += stu.getScores(i);
                avgscores[i] = sum[i] / a.length;
            }
        }
    }

    public void printLow() {
        for (int x : lowscores) {
            System.out.println("Low Score  " + x);
        }
    }

    public void printHigh() {
        for (int x : highscores) {
            System.out.println("High Score  " + x);
        }
    }

    public void printAvg() {
        for (float x : avgscores) {
            System.out.println("Average  " + x);
        }
    }
}

class Util {

    static Student[] readFile(String filename, Student[] stu) {
        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(file);
            int count = 0;

            boolean eof = false;
            while (!eof) {
                String line = buff.readLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                else {
                    System.out.println(line);

                    if (count > 0) {
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
                        for (int i = 0; i < stu.length; i++) {
                            stu[i] = new Student();
                        }
                        stu[count - 1].setSID(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
                        int scores[] = new int[5];
                        int scoreCount = 0;
                        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                            scores[scoreCount] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                            scoreCount++;
                            stu[count - 1].setScores(scores);
                        }
                    }
                }
                count++;
            }
            buff.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error -- " + e.toString());
        }
        return stu;
    }
}

public class Driver{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student lab4[] = new Student[40];
        lab4 = Util.readFile("C:\\lab4.txt", lab4);
        Statistics statlab4 = new Statistics();
        statlab4.findlow(lab4);
        statlab4.findhigh(lab4);
        statlab4.findavg(lab4);
        statlab4.printLow();
        statlab4.printHigh();
        statlab4.printAvg();
    }
}
```

The program reads an input file lab4.txt which includes 1 line of header and 15 lines of student records. The program runs but does not calculate the high low and average correctly. I know my calculation for average might be wrong; but I don't know why high and low don't work.

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried to remedy the situation? If your question is only here to obtain fixed code, then unfortunately you'll have to work for it.

Comment: My code initially failed to read the file and ran into a nullptr exception so I added a for loop for(int i=0; i< stu.length;i++) { stu[i] = new Student();} to create a new student object. I know my calculation of average might be wrong in the Statistics class but high should work. I added breakpoints to debug but couldn't figure out why. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thank you jake. I figured out my errors. Sorry for the confusion. This is the first time i asked a question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the find average, you shouldn't divide by `a.length` every iteration.

```
public void findavg(Student []a) {
    int []sum = new int [5];
    for(Student stu: a) {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            sum[i] += stu.getScores(i);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        avgscores[i] = sum[i] / a.length;
    }
}
```

The min and max seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned the `Statistics` class is required, I've taken another crack at your issue. And I see that when you calculate the highs and lows, the first loop is the students. Instead, make the first loop for the appropriate array, like so:

```
public void findLow(Student[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (Student stu : a)
            lowScores[i] = Math.min(stu.getScore(i), lowScores[i]);
}
```

What this then does is:

```
for each low score you want to find:
    for each student that took the quiz:
        if this student's score is lower, set that as the lowest
```

Apply the same logic to your `findHigh` method.

For your `findAvg` method, as previously stated, don't divide in every iteration:

```
public void findAvg(Student[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (Student s : a) {
            avgScores[i] += s.getScore(i);
        }
        avgScores[i] /= a.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! All 4 classes were required by the professor.

Comment: @SouthEast In that case, make `Statistics` a static class that takes one student at a time instead of all of them. Then just use `Statistics.printLow(someStudent);` I'll update my code if you need help, just let me know

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the confusion. Statistics class is to find the high, low,and average for a particular quiz, not for a student. That's why I included loops to look through every quiz by every student and find the min.

Comment: @SouthEast see my new answer, hopefully that solves your problems

Answer (score 0):

Not going to rewrite your code for you, just going to ask some questions because I think some people are still a bit confused about your purpose:

Is the purpose of the findAvg method to find the average of all the students marks for a particular test? Or to find the student's average mark for all of their tests?

Moving the Statistics class inside the methods of the Student class (as done by some of the other answers) would work if the latter is your goal, but I wouldn't mind keeping them separate if you're going for the former.

If you're trying to find the highest mark of a group of students, then I'd get them all into an Array or ArrayList and then try an ascending sort (or do them both at the same time).

```
public float avgCalculate(Student [] a, int testnumber){
    float sum = 0.0f;
    for (Student s: a){
        sum = sum + s.getScores[testnumber];
    }
    float average = (sum / a.length);
    return average;
}
```

Code is completely untested, so make sure it works and get back to me. It should calculate the average scores of a bunch of students (a) on a specific test (test number). Hopefully you can extrapolate the rest of the code (you may need to modify your other classes a bit etc.) For the highs and lows consider using the Arrays.sort() library method.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I've updated the question. findhigh,low and avg are all to calculate for a particular quiz, not to find the stats for a student.

Comment: Edited to include a sample method.